# SQLAlchemy : relationship Loading technique value at query level

Tags: sqlalchemy, lazy-loading, relationship, loading

I am using SQLAlchemy 1.4.3.

Starting from this very basic example :

```
class User(Base):
    id= Column(INTEGER(10), primary_key=True)
    symbols = relationship('Symbol', lazy="noload")
```

Then during a query, I change the relationship Loading technique from lazy='noload' to lazy='joined' with :

```
res = self.session.query(User).options(joinedload(User.symbols)).all()
```

From the result (`res` and only with that data) how can I get the current value of the relationship loading technique of the symbol relationship?

There are several ways to get this value at the Drug model level like :

```
res[0].__dict__.['_sa_instance_state'].mapper.relationships
```

(not the easiest one though). in this example, it will give me with the 'lazy' key : 'noload' which is the value at the model level.

But I am not able to get the updated value of the relationship loading technique matching the query done. (which should be lazy='joined')

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: You build the query and execute in one line: `self.session.query(User)...all()`. Can you split the query construction and execution so that you can inspect the query itself? E.g., `qry = self.session.query(User)...` and then `res = qry.all()`.

Comment: @SuperShoot, Thanks for you answer. I don't have the query data( from the portion of code I have access to, that's why I precised in my question "From the result (res and only with that data)"). Can't you have this info from the result ?

Comment: No problems, I was only trying to clarify your position. I don't have time to dig into it today and I'm not sure if loaded objects retain a reference to the query that loaded their data. One thing you might try is using an event listener to get the query such as: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.QueryEvents.before_compile

Answer (score 0):

A detailled explanation of how SQLAlchemy works for this part can be found on this thread : https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/6156